# Visual Studio 2012 and Git Extensions, checkout branch with removed files

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, git-extensions

I am using Visual Studio 2012 (11.0.61219.00 Update 5) with Git Extensions (GitExtensions-2.51.05.msi).

1. I cloned a remote repository
2. I created and checked out a new local branch "test_branch" where I deleted few project files (.cs and .txt files) using the Solution Explorer at the right side of Studio.
3. I committed all changes and added a message along with the commit.
4. I switched to the master branch where I could work with the files that were deleted while at test_branch.

I discovered that although the deleted files were recovered in the file system, Visual Studio would not automatically "see" them inside the project unless I manually added (Click on "show all files" button, select missing files and right-click->"include in project") the files again to the project. Is this normal behavior? I would expect that when I switch branches, all the files that belong to the branch are immediately "refreshed" on the Solution Explorer.

Thanks!

Comment: I think that your problem is that forgot to save and commit the `.csproj` file (need a "Save All) and so VS don't reload it and you're still with the one without the deleted files.

Comment: Ok, so Philippe if I understood you correctly: I deleted a file --> Saved All --> Commited --> Reverted last commit --> Saved All but still no file at the Solution Explorer. But now, I got closer because if I do "Unload Project" and "Reload Project" I see that the file's back at the Solution Explorer. Is it it then? Save All and then Reload manually?

Comment: Yes, you need to tell VS to reload project changes you made

Comment: I think that reloading the whole solution or some of the projects is not very productive every time I switch branch. It takes time and it should be automatic with branch check out

Comment: You are using a very old version of VS not planned to do that. Newer versions are detecting quite well changed and reload a lot faster.